# Scene Doesn't Change After Animation Complete

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot-4

I'm encountering an issue in Godot 4 with my 2D character where the "Hurt" animation plays correctly when the character's health reaches 0, but the scene does not change as expected. Here's my code:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

const SPEED = 300.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = -400.0

# Get the gravity from the project settings to be synced with RigidBody nodes.
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")
var health = 10
var is_dead = false

@onready var anim = get_node("AnimationPlayer")
@onready var sprite = get_node("AnimatedSprite2D")


func _physics_process(delta):
    # Add the gravity.
    if !is_dead:
        if not is_on_floor():
            velocity.y += gravity * delta

        # Handle Jump.
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and is_on_floor():
            velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY
            anim.play("Jump")

        # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
        # As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
        var direction = Input.get_axis("ui_left", "ui_right")
        if direction == -1:
            sprite.flip_h = true
        elif direction == 1:
            sprite.flip_h = false

        if direction:
            velocity.x = direction * SPEED
            if velocity.y == 0:
                anim.play("Run")
        else:
            velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
            if velocity.y == 0:
                anim.play("Idle")

        if velocity.y > 0:
            anim.play("Fall")
        move_and_slide()
    
    if health <= 0 and !is_dead:
        sprite.play("Hurt")
        is_dead = true
        print("Enter")
        await sprite.animation_finished
        print("Finish")
        queue_free()
        get_tree().change_scene_to_file("res://main.tscn")
```

Comment: Do you get the output from `print("Finish")`?

Comment: @Theraot no, only enter is printed

Answer (score 2):

If this part of the code is not running:

```
print("Finish")
queue_free()
get_tree().change_scene_to_file("res://main.tscn")
```

We conclude that the preceding line never returns:

```
await sprite.animation_finished
```

Which means that the `AnimatedSprite2D` never reports the animation as finished.

If the animation started (which you say it did), that means it never finished. Which would be the case if the animation is looping.

Thus: modify the animation to not loop, so it can finish, and the exaction flow can continue.

Comment: hurt animation only play once and then it goes to the idle

Comment: @Askani I do not see in the code anything else being played on the `AnimatedSprite2D`. I see you play `"Idle"` in the `AnimationPlayer`. Is the `AnimationPlayer` controlling the `AnimatedSprite2D`? That might be interrupting the `"Hurt"` animation instead of letting it finish. But sure, I'll give you an alternative that does not require figuring out what is going on: Use an [`SceneTreeTimer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_scenetreetimer.html#class-scenetreetimer).

Comment: sprite = get_node("AnimatedSprite2D"), i am using it for hurt animation and flip

Comment: here is my project folder >> https://github.com/sourcekode123/godotcode